# Commentary on "Amar H' Leya'akov"

Tags: prayer-book, song-poetry, motzei-shabbos

Do you know of any interesting commentaries on the song "Amar H' Leya'akov" that's part of the after-Shabbat liturgy?

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi *Yaakov* Emden's *sidur*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42977&st=&pgnum=404&hilite=) includes a brief commentary that says why the first half of each line implies that we should not fear.